# How to build path and file name for excel sheet from SMB share

Tags: powershell

I have below share and folders. For every month there will be a folder and there will be year folder prior to that as shown
[image]

Last Friday of every month there is excel sheet generated as shown below
[image]

End piece in file name "-14-26-48" remain same but prior pieces changes as per year and date. I would like to get this excel sheet path and name build in PowerShell. So how can i code so i get following path without manually entering complete path and filename. whenever i run new code i should get path and file name for last sheet which was generated last Friday of last month.

```
$oldbk = Import-Excel -Path '\\hcohesity05\cohesity_reports\2022\7\07-29\Cohesity_FETB_Report-2022-07-29-14-26-48.xlsx'
```

Comment: is that file generated monthly? or do you explicitly want to get the last Friday of the previous month? For example, sure, the last week day in July was a Friday so it makes sense to get the file from 2022\7\07-29, but the last week day in August was 2022\8\08-31, which was a Wednesday. Would that report exist in the 2022\8\08-31 path, and if it does would you want the report from the previous Friday anyway? If it is only generated on the last Friday, or if you want the last report generated for a given month this gets easy.

Comment: report generated on last Friday of every months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the file from the last Friday of the previous month the easiest way to find it is not to build the path, but just search a month's folders and filter for files created on a Friday, sort by time created, and get the first one (once sorted the last folder created will be the first item).

```
$LastMonth = [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyyy\\M')
$TargetFolder = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path '\\hcohesity05\cohesity_reports' $LastMonth) |Where{$_.CreationTime.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday'}|Sort CreationTime|Select -first 1
$FilePath = (Resolve-Path (Join-Path $TargetFolder.FullName 'Cohesity_FETB_Report-*-14-26-48.xlsx')).Path
$oldbk = Import-Excel -Path $FilePath
```

Comment: actually files are created every Friday but i am looking for last Friday of previous month.

Comment: This should get the last Friday's file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[DateTime]` type to help you out here.

```
# To do this, we create a new datetime, 
# (using the current month and year, but the first day).
$endOfMonth = [datetime]::new(
    [DateTime]::Now.Year,
    [DateTime]::Now.Month,
    1
).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)  
# Then we add a month to it and subtract a day
# (thus giving us the last day of the month)

# Now we create a variable for the last Friday
$lastFriday = $endOfMonth
# and we keep moving backward thru the calendar until it's right.
while ($lastFriday.DayOfWeek -ne 'Friday') {
   $lastFriday = $lastFriday.AddDays(-1) 
}

# At this point, we can make the ReportPath, piece by piece
# ($BasePath would be the path until this point)

$ReportPrefix = "Cohesity_FETB_Report"
$ReportSuffix = "14-26-48.xlsx"

$ReportPath = Join-Path $BasePath $lastFriday.Year |
    Join-Path -ChildPath $lastFriday.Month |
    # A Custom format string will be needed for the month/day
    Join-Path -ChildPath $lastFriday.ToString("MM-dd") | 
    Join-Path -ChildPath "$reportPrefix-$($lastFriday.ToString('YYYY-MM-dd'))-$reportSuffix"

$reportPath
```

Comment: Skip the `.AddMonths(1)` on line 7, or else you'll get the last Friday of the current month (most likely a date in the future). The OP said they need the last Friday of the previous month.

Comment: above code just hang and don't show any output. Can you also include complete path including share names too (\\hcohesity05\cohesity_reports\2022\8\08-26\Cohesity_FETB_Report-2022-08-26-14-26-48.xlsx) ?

Comment: To be fair, it would be best to provide the original [DateTime] as a parameter.  The .AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) will be needed to get the last day of a given month.